# The appCompat, Navigation and Lifecycle imports in all my projects are giving errors

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, dependencies

I was working with a project that has modules and then somehow i ran into something that caused all the problems. I am unable to pinpoint the issue. But all my projects are now giving errors.

I wanted to make the build successful although now the project builds and all but I am unable to write code due to the errors.

Comment: when i change a dependency and sync, the errors go away and when i rebuild the project they appear again